# What is the frobenius map really?

Tags: number-theory, category-theory, finite-fields

I know what the frobenius map is the naive sense, just the $p$th power map on an $\mathbb{F}_p$ algebra, and that this can be upgraded somewhat to the generator of the monoid of natural transformations on the identity functor on $\mathbb{F}_p$ algebras. To my knowledge, this is the reason it pops up anywhere one has anything of/over characteristic $p$.

For instance, the frobenius morphism I have seen in algebraic geometry seem to just be unwinding the definitions down until we get elements of an $\mathbb{F}_p$ algebra, then applying this down to earth frobenius map.

However, this doesn't seem fully satisfactory, in that before doing any of this, we fix a prime $p$, and use the frobenius map in this fixed characteristic.

So my question is this:

In what sense are the frobenius maps for different $p$ the same thing, can they be viewed as manifestations of the same underlying morphism of something?

Comment: Isn't the Frobenius map the only nonidentity endomorphism of $\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbf{Fld}_p}$ (with suggestive notations) ? In any case, great question !

Comment: @Max For that to be true, it'd have to square to either itself or to the identity natural transformation, no?

Comment: @KevinCarlson : I meant to edit and say "generates the monoid of endomorphisms" but couldn't and hoped it would be clear from context haha